# error importing pptx library python

Tags: python, powerpoint

i want to import pptx but i'm using this

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,'D:/apera/python27/python-pptx-0.5.6')

import pptx
```

but somehow it shows error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/apera/Workspace/Python scripting test 6/ppt.py", line 5, in <module>
import pptx
File "D:/apera/python27/python-pptx-0.5.6\pptx\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from pptx.api import Presentation  # noqa
File "D:/apera/python27/python-pptx-0.5.6\pptx\api.py", line 14, in <module>
from pptx.package import Package
File "D:/apera/python27/python-pptx-0.5.6\pptx\package.py", line 16, in <module>
from .parts.image import Image, ImagePart
 File "D:/apera/python27/python-pptx-0.5.6\pptx\parts\image.py", line 13, in <module>
 import Image as PIL_Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

and when i want to install PIL it can't install for 64 bit. Is there a ppt library that don't need PIL?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your application can't run as a 32-bit? I think that might be the easiest solution.

Comment: PIL in main website don't have the install for 64-bit. I think i''l try with VM for 32 bit one

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use pip to install it?  Installs fine for me in a 64-bit windows 2.7 virtualenv. pip install python-pptx.  Oh... and Pillow replaced PIL.

Comment: you're right used pillow!

Comment: Install Pillow from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow). Download the `.whl`, then run `pip install wheelfilename.whl`

Answer (score 1):

remove the PIL package due to conflicts with Pillow and python-pptx

- Delete the PIL directory located in C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\ or wherever your library is
- run `pip install python-pptx` to install Pillow

Answer (score 0):

I had about the same issue. When I updated the pillow library (pretty easy to do with Anaconda which I use) the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Pillow
2. Uninstall python-pptx
3. Install Pillow
4. Install python-pptx

Run above commands using "pip". This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My system is Windows XP 32bit and the python version is 2.7.13.
I just degraded the version of pillow and python-pptx. It worked for me

```
pip install pillow==3.1.0
pip install python-pptx==0.5.5
```